# Can anyone help me understand this part of a proof involving inverse limits?

Tags: limits, category-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have very little knowledge on inverse limits, in fact I only started reading about it when I came across it on this particular proof for a theorem on the general criterion of the existence of roots of 1-Lipschitz functions. I hope someone could help me understand this part of the proof:

Given:

$\bullet f: \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p \text{ f is 1-Lipschitz and continuous }\\
\bullet f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p^k} \text{ has a solution } \forall k >0 \\
\bullet M_k \subset \{0,1,2,...,p^k-1\} \text{ be the set of all solutions of the congruence above}\\
\bullet h_i \in M_i \\
\bullet \mathbb{M} \text{ is the set of all possible sequences } \{h_1, h_2, h_3, ..., h_k,... \} \\
\bullet f(b_i) \equiv f(a_k) \equiv 0\pmod{p^i}, \text{ such that } b_i \in M_i \text{ and }  a_k\in M_k \\
\bullet \varprojlim M_k = \mathbb{M}$

And this is the excerpt from the proof which I want to understand on how they came up with the conclusion

$$ \text{Since } f \text{ is continuous }\\
\text{then } f(a)=0, \forall a\in \mathbb{M}  $$

I hope someone could explain to me how that happened. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that you can write $\Bbb Z_p \simeq \varprojlim \Bbb Z /p^k$? It seems that this is just a very formal way of applying this. However, some of your hypotheses seem redundant, and in particular the penultimate one is unclear, it lacks quantors *and* seems to show the wrong congruence: Maybe what is meant is *for all* $a_k \in M_k$ *there exists* $b_i \in M_i$ (where wlog $i \le k$) such that $b_i \equiv a_k$ mod $p^i$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg yes that is right